# BadRequest when calling graph create team API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Following [the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0#example-2-application-permissions), I tested it in Graph Explorer, but got a the below error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid bind property name owners in request.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-08-27T02:29:37",
            "request-id": "1c1d5961-201d-449b-ad1d-8b4a328bd91c"
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can take a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the graph v1.0 api of create team doesn't work for now, replace it to beta is currently a workaround for me. Here is the original post:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Unknown-error-when-using-HTTP-action-to-call-graph-API-Create-a/m-p/670617#M90238